# What is the goal of current US lockdown measures?

Tags: covid-19

In March 2020 in the US, in my opinion, lockdown measures were clearly motivated and explained: the goal is to avoid overwhelming the health care system, and the method was to use lockdowns and other similar measures to stall for time while new health care facilities were built (e.g. hospitals and ventilators).

In May 2020, it seems we've achieved the goal of expanding the availability of health care *well* beyond what we expected to need to deal with COVID-19 infections.

Thus, the motivation for continued lockdowns seems less clear<sup>1</sup>. So my question is:

> What is the goal that politicians are currently aiming for, and how does continued lockdowns support it?

<sup>1: Note I'm deliberately assuming noble intent and informed decision making, and I'm seeking information that would support this assumption.</sup>

Comment: I'm voting this as opinion-based. It's also not really about Medical Sciences but about the opinions of politicians. Maybe Politics.SE could be appropriate, but then again it's also too broad in that there are many many politicians with different motivations, and even individual politicians, like always in politics, have multiple motivations.

Comment: @BryanKrause Well, I (think) in this post I'm not so much interested in understanding the political motivations, but rather in understanding what concrete plans exist for dealing with the pandemic that would incorporate lockdowns, especially of the form we're seeing. Having a better understanding of what people might be trying to achieve would better help be contextualize the actual policies and rhetoric.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. I think at this point you just have to rely on expert individuals that you trust. It's probably worth not relying solely on federal health officials, because it is unknown how much political pressure they may be under (for example, balancing their public statements between the information they feel is key to release and wanting to keep their job lest they be replaced with someone useless). I think looking for "concrete plans" is a bit of a mistake because those don't exist, and in any case it's not great to encase any plan in concrete.

Comment: @BryanKrause I think you're maybe taking "concrete" more harshly than I meant it; e.g. "the lockdown slows the spread, letting us stall for time while we build enough health care capacity for the short term and long term" counts as a concrete plan, as I meant the term, to contrast with "lockdown...  because we should lockdown" which is basically all I'm seeing now. I'm naively hoping medicalsciences.stackexchange.com is a place where I might be able to communicate with, if not an expert individual, someone with sufficient expertise to satisfy my lack of knowledge.

Comment: (mind you, I'm not saying "lockdown because we should lock down" is the *only* pro-lockdown sentiment being said -- it's just that better explanations are either not being provided in the venues I'm seeing, or maybe just they're not made clearly and prominently enough that I'm aware they're being given)

Comment: "lockdown... because we should lockdown" to me seems to be in strong conflict with "I'm deliberately assuming noble intent and informed decision making" and also I haven't heard anyone make such a generic claim.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: In particular, you need to provide support for this claim: `"In May 2020, it seems we've achieved the goal of expanding the availability of health care well beyond what we expected to need to deal with COVID-19 infections."` Most states are still on the upslope side of the curve and haven't peaked yet, and the states on the downslope side are there precisely _because_ of the lockdown measures. Without them, NYC would almost certainly have exceeded their capacity by now and would still be on the upslope.

Comment: @BryanKrause Assuming noble intent and informed decision making means that when I hear what is basically "lockdown... because we should lockdown," I presume it's a failure of *communication*, and look to other sources.

Comment: @AdriftInCovid Maybe it would be helpful if you could point to one of these failures in communication.

Comment: @AdriftInCovid The reasons for the lockdown have been explained widely in the press, by the CDC, by Dr. Fauci, and dozens of other authoritative sources in the US and other countries. As I said above, we require prior research, so that leaves me wondering why I don't see the phrase "flatten the curve" in your question. **So this is my second request for you to do a little homework and edit your question to add what you've learned.**

Comment: OK, so your **opinion** is that physical distancing had the goal of overwhelming the heathcare system. My **opinion** is that the avoidance of swamping the H/C system was the one of the goals, one that had to be dealt with urgently, but there was another goal - mediating the death and damage to the people. Consider for a moment  a disease that would kill 1 million in spite on an infinite number of beds, vents and PPE available. But, by using behavior modification (physical distancing) the number could be cut substantially.  So, regardless of equipment, physical distancing is a useful tool.

Comment: Possibly see https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53165/what-caused-the-shift-from-flattening-the-curve-to-disease-eradication-in-west (but I think the US is not touched there because of their complex political [federal] system) Perhaps see https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/53265/18373 on the latter.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of lock downs is to enforce social distancing and other measures to break the chain of disease transmission.  There is no data to suggest that has occurred yet in the USA.

Many countries that have employed mandatory lockdown have successfully contained the virus and stopped community transmission.  China was the first successful example of this though there has now been a small outbreak of 6 cases in a residential compound in Wuhan, and the city of Shulan is in lockdown with 3 new cases reported.  China has also just ordered the [testing of the 11 million residents](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/coronavirus-wuhan-orders-all-residents-tested-six-new-cases-2020-5?r=US&IR=T) of Wuhan.

Taiwan managed to contain the pandemic without lockdown but used early border controls, aggressive quarantine, and contact tracing as well as other social policies.  They had 7 deaths in a population just larger than Sweden.

New Zealand is emerging out of lockdown with people being allowed to return to work from tomorrow.  0 - 3 cases daily have been reported in the last week. NZ has had 20 deaths in a population of 5M.  Sweden, which did not enforce lockdown, but relied on the public to adopt voluntary social distancing, has had 3,300 deaths with twice the population size.  If you calculate the rate for the USA using Sweden as the basis, you would expect to see 33 * 3,300 = 108,900 deaths but so far the number of deaths has been 83,000 approx.  So, as the USA eases its lockdown policies without evidence of controlling the chain of transmission, expect to see many more deaths.

https://www.dw.com/en/taiwan-coronavirus/a-52724523
https://medicalxpress.com/news/2020-05-china-wuhan-virus-infection-month.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Sweden